# Setting the environment for ProcessBuilder

Tags: java, environment-variables, processbuilder

I have a strange problem setting the Linux environment from Java (1.6); specifically the "PATH" variable.

In a nutshell, I have a pipeline for running native processes, which uses `java.lang.ProcessBuilder`. The user can optionally set the environment variables via a `HashMap` named `environment`:

```
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder(args);
Map<String, String> env = pb.environment();
if (environment != null)
   env.putAll(environment);
Process process = pb.start();
```

The `env` variable gets set properly, if I dump it to the console, with a correct value for the PATH variable. However, running the process results in a thrown `Exception`:

`java.io.IOException: error=2, No such file or directory`

The same process runs fine with identical environment variables in the terminal shell. To test this, I ran Eclipse AFTER setting the environment in the terminal. In this case the `ProcessBuilder` process runs correctly.

So what must be happening is that the `ProcessBuilder` is not using the environment I set for it, but the current System environment instead.

I can't find any satisfactory answers to this problem online. Perhaps this is an OS-specific issue? Or something else I'm missing?

Comment: Maybe try to sysout the PATH variable and post it here, maybe we can spot something..

Comment: Another thing to be aware of in Windows is that while case of environment variable names is _"typically not important"_ (to quote the `System.getenv` javadoc), such that you may call `System.getenv("path")` or `System.getenv("PATH")` interchangeably with similar results, the same is not true for the environment field of ProcessBuilder since the `Map` is accessed directly rather than through a specific getter, so any discrepancy in capitalization will result in error... Hint: if you **do** want to get the path of a ProcessBuilder in Windows, use `environment.get("Path")`.

Comment: @PeterT The Hint you gave saying use Path on windows was amazing !!! I spent weeks together because of this problem in ProcessBuilder!! THANKS A LOT !!! :) :)

Comment: @Destructor glad to help... I can't remember how long it foiled me for: not quite weeks, but long enough to be frustrating :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to understand that environment variables are local to process contexts. A new process gets a copy of the parent's environment but each copy is independent. Changes in the parent don't affect existing children (only new ones) and changes in children don't affect the parent or new children of the *parent*.

In your case, the Java process creates child process and puts a modified `PATH` variable into the child's context. This doesn't affect the Java process. The child process isn't a shell, so it ignores the `PATH` variable. The process is created directly using OS services. Those look into the context of the Java process which contains the old `PATH` variable unless you change the environment in the shell *before* you start the Java process.

To fix your issue, you have two choices:

1. Examine the `PATH` variable in Java, split it into path elements and search for the executable manually. You can then invoke `ProcessBuilder` with the absolute path *and* put the new `PATH` into the child, so grandchildren will have the correct path.
2. Invoke a shell to start the child process. The shell will use it's path (which you can pass via the environment).

The second case works like this:

1. You create an environment with the correct `PATH`.
2. You start a shell process.
3. You pass the command to run as argument to the shell (`"sh", "-c", "cmd args"` or `"cmd.exe", "/c", "cmd args"`)
4. The shell will notice that it has to run a command
5. It will look into it's environment (which you configured in step #1), find the modified `PATH` and run the correct command.

The drawback of the second case is that you have to properly escape and/or quote the arguments for the command (`args`), or spaces and other special characters will cause problems.

Answer (score 17):

I don't think it's a bug, I think it's a problem with your understanding of the boundaries and roles of the environment variables at play.  `ProcessBuilder.environment()` contains environment variables that will be "process-local" to the spawned process.  They are not system-wide, or logon-wide, and they don't even affect the environment in which the ProcessBuilder is running.

The `ProcessBuilder.environment()` map contains process-local variables that will be seen **only** by the spawned process.  Obviously a prerequisite to the spawned processing seeing the `ProcessBuilder.environment()` is successful spawning of the process, which is a point I do not think you're even getting to.

As far as I know, it's not really possible (from Java) to modify the currently-running process' PATH, which is what I think you're expecting to happen (or to be able to do.)  So I think you must point ProcessBuilder to the fully qualified path to the executable you're trying to launch (or be certain that the PATH was set up correctly before you even launch the JVM that will use the ProcessBuilder, which is what you did in your 'working' scenario of setting it in the terminal before launching your IDE).

Comment: Thanks, this is very helpful. Presuming I specify the full path to the target process, does this mean that it will use the `ProcessBuilder`'s process-local environment variables if it makes its own calls to other processes? That would be a suitable solution for me.

Comment: I'm not certain I fully understand (especially with regards to "calls to other processes"), but I'm pretty sure the answer is yes.

Comment: I got your point. Can you point me to the docs which specify the same?

Answer (score 8):

On Linux:

```
String path = System.getenv("HOME");

ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("/bin/bash","-c","export PATH=" +
    "PATH-TO-ADD" + ":" + path + " && exec");
```

In this case the `PATH` variable is updated as per the need and the executable is searched in new `$PATH`. This worked for me on Linux.

Comment: Or run a sh file and edit that to have the variables you need before executing within that sh script

Answer (score 2):

One thing that is clear from the ProcessBuilder javadoc is that you can get the environment variables with the environment() method, and then *modify* the returned map.  Any *subsequent* process that is launched from that ProcessBuilder instance will have your changes.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're right. The currently executing java code will not use the environment variables you are preparing for the child process you are executing. You could create an intermediate executable or script that you can pass variables to and have it execute your program.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a real issue with java and external processes

the following on windows 7 and java 7 (32bit)

```
ProcessBuilder b = new ProcessBuilder();
Map<String, String> env = b.environment();
for (String key : env.keySet())
     System.out.println(key + ": " + env.get(key));
```

produces

```
SystemRoot: C:\Windows
Path: xbox
```

**which means the running programs environment and the subprocesses environment should contain a path variable, that has exactly the value 'xbox'** (e.g. nonsense, there is no directory named xbox anywhere on my pc)

just for protocol:

```
Map<String, String> env = System.getenv();
    for (String key : env.keySet())
        System.out.println(key + ": " + env.get(key));
```

gives exactly the same result.

when I run

```
b.command("convert.exe", "/?").inheritIO().start();
```

with this process builder and environment I get

```
    Konvertiert FAT-Volumes in NTFS.

CONVERT Volume /FS:NTFS [/V] [/CvtArea:Dateiname] [/NoSecurity] [/X]

  Volume      Bestimmt den Laufwerkbuchstaben (gefolgt von einem Doppelpunkt),
              den Bereitstellungspunkt oder das Volume.
  /FS:NTFS    Bestimmt das in NTFS zu konvertierende Volume.
  /V          Legt fest, dass CONVERT im ausf�hrlichen Modus ausgef�hrt wird.
  /CvtArea:Dateiname
              Bestimmt die zusammenh�ngende Datei im Stammverzeichnis, die als
              Platzhalter f�r NTFS-Systemdateien dienen soll.
  /NoSecurity Bestimmt die Sicherheitseinstellungen f�r konvertierte Dateien
              und Verzeichnisse, die f�r jeden Benutzer zug�nglich sind.
  /X          Erzwingt ggf. das Aufheben der Bereitstellung.
              Alle ge�ffneten Handles auf das Volume sind in diesem Fall 
              ung�ltig.
```

this is the (german) output of

```
C:\Windows\System32\convert.exe
```

The same happens when I use

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[]{"convert.exe", "/?"});
```

And note that my environment is so small because I replaced the native enviroment. That means the whole program has exactly those two environment variables.