# Platform-independent way to start program on PATH?

Tags: java

Is there a **platform-independent** way in Java to start an external process that executes program which it finds using the **system path**?

It should work at least on Windows, Linux and Mac.

---

Normally your have to give the full path to an executable file, like this:

```
new ProcessBuilder("/some/path/execfile", "arg").start();
```

It is possible to start a program that is on the system path by starting a shell:

```
new ProcessBuilder("/bin/bash", "-c", "execfile", "arg").start();
```

But this is not portable between OS:s. (This is the solution that is given to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26992165/how-to-set-path-environment-variable-in-processbuilder-java-in-windows).)

Comment: It's weird if this problem don't have a solution already, but I really couldn't find anything.

Comment: The executable file will be called exactly the same? If so, why don't you pass the location of said file as either an arg or a environment variable? `System#getProperty` and `System#getenv`, repectivelly.

Comment: @JettoMartínez: That is a possibility... But a little inconvenient...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ProcessBuilder` does use the `$PATH`.

```java
import java.io.*;

public class ProcessBuilderTest {
    public static void main(String... args) throws Exception {
        ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder(args);
        pb.redirectErrorStream(true);
        Process p = pb.start();
        int exitCode = p.waitFor();
        printStream(p.getInputStream());
        printStream(p.getErrorStream());
        System.out.println("Exit code: " + exitCode);
    }

    static void printStream(InputStream stream) throws IOException {
        try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(stream))) {
            String line;
            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                System.out.println(line);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Running this on MacOS:

```bash
robert@mac:~$ java ProcessBuilderTest.java ls *.java
ProcessBuilderTest.java
Exit code: 0
robert@mac:~$ java ProcessBuilderTest.java ls *.class
ls: cannot access '*.class': No such file or directory
Exit code: 2
robert@mac:~$ java ProcessBuilderTest.java which ls
/usr/local/opt/coreutils/libexec/gnubin/ls
Exit code: 0
robert@mac:~$
```

Same on Linux:

```bash
robert@linux:~$ java ProcessBuilderTest.java ls *.java
ProcessBuilderTest.java
Exit code: 0
robert@linux:~$ java ProcessBuilderTest.java ls  *.class
ls: cannot access '*.class': No such file or directory
Exit code: 2
robert@linux:~$ java ProcessBuilderTest.java which ls
/usr/bin/ls
Exit code: 0
robert@linux:~$
```

I don't use Windows, so cannot test on that.

Comment: Hah! It does! Thanks! I was fooled by two things: Eclipse starts programs with an empty environment. And I was trying to start `mvn`, but you have to use `mvn.cmd` instead.

Comment: PS: Now days you can print the output of a process like this: `System.out.println(new String(process.getInputStream().readAllBytes()));`