# Running JHipster Gradle task from Intellij IDEA

Tags: intellij-idea, spring-boot, jhipster

This error happens when I run with Gradle through from Intellij IDEA.. but from console everything works fine... someone knows why?

> Executing external task 'run --stacktrace'... :compileJava UP-TO-DATE
>   :compileScala UP-TO-DATE :bower FAILED
>
> org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task
>   ':bower'.
>
> Caused by: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "bower" (in
>   directory "/Users/eduardo/Development/projects/jhipster"): error=2, No
>   such file or directory

Comment: Where is "bower"? Would you please try to open Terminal in IDEA and try "which bower" to see if IDEA can find "bower"?

Comment: from Terminal in IDEA... everything works...                                               which bower
/Users/eduardo/.nvm/versions/node/v0.12.2/bin/bower

Comment: Would you please post the build file?

Answer (score 12):

I contacted JetBrains support about this. The one thing they suggested was running IntelliJ from the command line, which is working for me:

```
open -a "/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA 15.app"
```

Comment: This also works for STS/Eclipse by running open -a "Applications/STS.app"

Answer (score 6):

At a guess, you are running IntelliJ on OSX, maybe with a brew install of bower?

Recent versions of OSX (at least 10.10.1) don't let you easily set the PATH for graphical applications (launchctl seems to have a bug in regards to PATH).  Combined with there being no way to modify the current environment PATH for launching subprocesses in Java, this results in being unable to find the bower executable.  A Complete rundown of the root problem can be seen here ([Setting the environment for ProcessBuilder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10035383/setting-the-environment-for-processbuilder)), but essentially IntelliJ must have your PATH set correctly in order for non standard PATHs to be searched.

My solution for now is a complete hack taken from https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/51737 - essentially, create a wrapper script:

create `/Application/IntelliJ\ IDEA\ 14.app/Contents/MacOS/idea.sh` with contents of:

```
#!/bin/sh

. ~/.bash_profile

logger "`dirname \"$0\"`/idea"

exec "`dirname \"$0\"`/idea" $@
```

then `chmod +x /Application/IntelliJ\ IDEA\ 14.app/Contents/MacOS/idea.sh`

then edit `/Application/IntelliJ\ IDEA\ 14.app/Contents/Info.plist` and set `CFBundleExecutable` to `idea.sh`

lastly, run `/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Frameworks/LaunchServices.framework/Support/lsregister -v -f /Applications/IntelliJ\ IDEA\ 14.app`

It's a hack, *but it works*...  and until Apple fixes launchctl, it's the only solution I've come up with.

Comment: It works! Thanks! I used `/Applications/...` instead of `/Application...`

Comment: dosen't work for me. is it because I'm using IDEA 15?

Comment: Try changing the command to use the path to your IntelliJ installation.

Comment: Not working anymore. 
OSX 10.11.3 and IntelliJ Idea 15

Comment: This is great but much easier to do. The procedure can be reduced 3 steps: 1) move the idea executable to idea_app , 2) create new file called idea and  enter your shell script there, point to idea_app from it 3) chmod +x idea - and you are done. Nice