# Not able to run cmd command through java

Tags: java, cmd, processbuilder

I have a `.bat` file called `galen.bat`. I included the path to this file in the `PATH` environment variable.

When I run:

```
galen.bat --version
```

in `cmd`, I get the following output:

```
Galen Framework
Version: 1.6.3
JavaScript executor: Rhino 1.7 release 5 2015 01 29
```

I have the following `java` code through which I'm trying to run the same command through my application -

```
 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
            ProcessBuilder builder = new ProcessBuilder(
                "cmd.exe", "/c", "galen.bat --version");
            builder.redirectErrorStream(true);
            Process p = builder.start();
            BufferedReader r = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
            String line;
            while (true) {
                line = r.readLine();
                if (line == null) { break; }
                System.out.println(line);
            }
        }
```

When I run this I get the following error -

```
'galen.bat' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

Please note that if I use

```
ProcessBuilder builder = new ProcessBuilder(
                    "cmd.exe", "/c", "java -version");
```

instead of

```
ProcessBuilder builder = new ProcessBuilder(
                    "cmd.exe", "/c", "galen.bat --version");
```

then I do get the correct output in my eclipse console window -

```
java version "1.7.0_03"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_03-b05)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 22.1-b02, mixed mode)
```

Why is `galen.bat --version` not working? How do I fix this?
Thanks!

Comment: Did you tried giving full path of `.bat` file?

Comment: Try providing the full path to the bat file, or (maybe less usefully) place it in the working directory of the java app.

Comment: your whole code is a copy of this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15464111/run-cmd-commands-through-java where it has been clearly mentioned what it has done .. that is missing in your code.. read that answer carefully

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According [the docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/env.html):

> When a Java application uses a ProcessBuilder object to create a new process, the default set of environment variables **passed to the new process is the same set provided to the application's virtual machine process**. The application can change this set using ProcessBuilder.environment.

So you must include the new path of `galen.bat` in the path of your JVM or change `ProcessBuilder.environment` to your system `PATH`, but [according this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10036389/3850595), seems last option is not possible.